# Count the times an iFrame reloads in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have 5 iframes in my website.
These iframes have a source of 3rd party site which is not mine.

I'm trying to know how many times the iframes are reloaded. iFrames can be reloaded as many times as an user wants.

Here you have code and jsFiddle

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var timesRefreshed = 0;
$("iframe").load(function(){
    if(timesRefreshed == 2){
        alert("HOLA");
    }
    timesRefreshed++; 
});​
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.miipodtouch.com"></iframe>​
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCRDF/

I don't know why it doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: you have to select jquery from the left menu bar under frameworks

Comment: a okey. no, i've tested that code in my pc without jsfiddle, and it doesn't work.

Comment: it works! but i dont know why using the link from google apis doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Script should be in this fashion:

```
$(function() {

var timesRefreshed = 0;
$("iframe").load(function(){
    if(timesRefreshed == 2){
        alert("HOLA");
    }
    timesRefreshed++; 
});​


});
```

That means you should be wrapping your jQuery snippet inside a document. ready function which is called as

```
$(function() {
  // code here
});
```

**OR**

```
$("document").ready(function() {
     // code here
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work and i don't why. it's very strange because i've changed what you say @3nigma and it has worked once, very strange :S and i've changed what you say and it doesn't work

Comment: @frankie3 your jsfiddle is using Mootools - change that to jquery